# How to create different Wordpress usertypes

Tags: php, wordpress, registration, multiple-users

I'm a newbie.  What I ultimately need is a capability on Wordpress to create different usertypes where each user will have access to certain plugins.
For example: students will have access to plugins A and B, teachers will have access to plugin B and C, schools will have access to plugins A, B , and C.
So, each usertype will have to register through a dedicated form. 
I could not find such plugin with these features.  I'd greatly appreciate any guidance to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about wordpress. try wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: there are many plugins to achieve this, try doing a search for "User Role Wp plugin" and you'll see many

Answer (score 0):

Accessing individual plugins on a user-level basis is interesting. What kind of plugins would you want to protect? I would think it would be content pages?

But, to answer your question, look into the [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) plugin. It allows you to create a group that a user can belong to, and each group can be assigned capabilities (and create new capabilities) - it's far more thorough than the standard WordPress User Level.